# Preference wont change in my main activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In my MainActivity I have a textView.
In that textView there is a Number that I keep in a SharedPreferences. 
and every couple of min The SharedPreferences is changed with an alarm manager,
but the SharedPreferences in my MainActivity wont change,
anyone has an idea why?

this is a part of The code in the MainActivity

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int ReleaseDate = preferences.getInt("com.fisher.freedom.ReleaseDate", 0);
    TextView edit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DaysLeft);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + preferences.getInt("com.fisher.freedom.ReleaseDate", 0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    edit.setText("" + ReleaseDate);
```

This is the code in the AlarmReceiver

```
    public static final String ReleaseDate_Key = "com.fisher.freedom.ReleaseDate";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        int ReleaseDate = preferences.getInt(ReleaseDate_Key, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(ReleaseDate_Key, --ReleaseDate);
        editor.apply();
```

Comment: in which event handler do you set the text view value?

Comment: I don't think its really matters cause I also made a toast of the value and every time I open the app the value is the same even if the value has change in the alarm receiver

Answer (score 0):

For get the value of your int use this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),0);
int ReleaseDate = sharedPreferences.getInt("ReleaseDate",0);
```

And to save it use this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putInt("ReleaseDate", ReleaseDate).commit();
```

With this you forget about writing on static variable your package name, it worked for me, so it's going for you.

Comment: Thank you But I am having the same problem, 
The value of the sharedPreferences don't change in the MainActivity,
Its changes only when I am destroying and then restarting the app.

Comment: @cperez Did you know? `apply()` is faster than `commit()`, because it's asynchronous and doesn't return a value, It requires API Level 9+

Comment: Yes I know, Thank you

Comment: I solved the problem, the SharedPreferences value didn't change because in the Manifest the receiver was remote